# How to create UIImageView with stretchable image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

In my app one requirement is to set background of label to some image. I have done it by setting image at the back of UIlabel by this code

.H file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *lblBGIV;
} 
@end
```

.M file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    lblBGIV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    UIImage *lblBGImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"textlblbg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8)];

    lblBGIV.image = lblBGImg;
}

- (void)updateLabelMethod:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

            lblBGIV.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x-9, label.frame.origin.y-5, label.frame.size.width+18, 26);

            [self.myScrollView addSubview:lblBGIV];
            [self.myScrollView sendSubviewToBack:lblBGIV];
}
```

Comment: Could you add textlblbg.png as it is to the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create different code for setting image for different iOS. use this code,

```
UIImage *lblBGImg;
    float currentVersion = 6.0;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= currentVersion)
    {
        //device have iOS 6 or above
        lblBGImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"textlblbg41.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)  resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    }else{
        //device have iOS 5.1 or belove
        lblBGImg = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"textlblbg41.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15.0 topCapHeight:15.0];
    }
    lblBGIV.image = lblBGImg;
```

This will Do the trick for both iOS.

Comment: Instead of checking the iOS version, Apple recommends checking if the object responds to the selector. `if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:)]) {...}` (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-107026)

Answer (score 5):

Use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` instead.

```
UIImage *lblBGImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"textlblbg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Comment: @Kane It is available only in iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
UIImage(named: "videoSliderFiller")?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch)
```